# How to use IPP FIRGenBandStop method?

Tags: finite-impulse-response

Following this link:
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/ipp_sa/80/ipp_manual/GUID-5457048E-3C59-43E4-8A99-FB3873DCB769.htm
I have produced the following code:

```
        const int len = 512;
        Ipp64f pInputSignal[len];

        int tapslen = 27;
        int numIters = len;

        IppsFIRState_64f* pState;
        IppStatus status;

        Ipp64f* pOutputSignal = ippsMalloc_64f(len*sizeof(Ipp64f));
        Ipp64f* taps = ippsMalloc_64f(tapslen*sizeof(Ipp64f));
        Ipp64f* pDL = ippsMalloc_64f(tapslen*sizeof(Ipp64f));

        ippsZero_64f(pDL,tapslen);
        float sample_rate = 48000.0;//Hz //TODO DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE
        float frequency = 400.0;//Hz
        float amplitude = 2000.0;

        //Fill pInputSignal[t] = 2*pi*frequency*t, where t is time from t[i] = i/sample_rate
        fillBufferWithSinusoidData_64f(pInputSignal,len,sample_rate,frequency,amplitude);

        //computes tapsLen coefficients for bandstop  FIR filter
        float rFreqLow  = (frequency-52.0)/(sample_rate);
        float rFreqHigh = (frequency+51.0)/(sample_rate);

        status = ippsFIRGenBandstop_64f(
            rFreqLow,
            rFreqHigh,
            taps, 
            tapslen, 
            ippWinHamming, 
            ippTrue);
        Assert::AreEqual((int)IppStatus::ippStsNoErr,(int)status);

        ////filter an input vector
        status = ippsFIRInitAlloc_64f(&pState, taps,tapslen, pDL);
        status = ippsFIR_64f(pInputSignal, pOutputSignal, numIters, pState);
```

In other words: 
Input is a sinusoid at frequency 400Hz
Band stop between 348.0Hz to 451Hz

Expected output : something flat (as I would expect the sine signal would get filtered out).

Actual output : Sine wave moves 1/2 phase, magnitude is lowered a bit.

Any ideas about what went wrong here?

Comment: Generally, these sorts of questions are off-topic for DSP.SE as they tend to be programming questions rather than strictly DSP. You might have to debug them using some DSP knowledge, but you can flag them with the `[signal-processing]` tag on SO for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with the code.
1. There seems to be a problem number of taps used for frequency. For filtering 400Hz sine wave at samplerate 48KHz I get better results if I use tapslen more than 559. 
2. ippsFIRGenBandstop apparently is implemented as band pass + band stop + band pass. By doing this IPP tends to add some ripple at the higher end (around 44,000 and above). See here:
[image]

When using this filter it is recommended to use some kind of a FIR filter design tool like TFilter: http://t-filter.appspot.com/fir/index.html
Or matlab FIR filter design toolbox.